# How do I find the variance and covariance of ranks of independent RVs?

Tags: self-study, distributions, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

[image]

I know how to prove (a), while I don't have idea on(b). It would be nice if u can give me some hints

"$R_1,... R_n$ are their Wilcoxon singed ranks" means the absolute rank of $X_i-m$. Here $m = 0$, so it is equal  to absolute rank of $X_i$.

Comment: "$R_1, ..., R_n$ are their Wilcoxon singed [sic] ranks" - can you please explain what this means? The Wilcoxon test applies to *pairs*, AFAIK. Is $R_i$ simply the rank of the $i$th smallest outcome from $X_1, ..., X_n$? This could be the case if $X_i$ is *defined* as the difference between some pair.

Comment: I have edited  the qeustion

Comment: Oh, so the pairs are implied by one of each being the median. OK.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for finding the marginal CDF of the $i$th Rank**

Say some random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent, with CDFs $F_{X_1}(x) = \cdots = F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x)$.

- For some fixed subset of size $j$ of the RVs:

  - The probability that all RVs in the subset are less than $x$, is $F_X(x)^j$.
  - The probability that all RVs in the subset are greater or equal to $x$, is $\left(1 - F_X(x)\right)^j$.
- The probability that exactly the $j$ smallest RVs are less than $x$, is the number of ways of choosing *j* from *n*, times the probability that $j$ RVs are smaller than $x$, times the probability that $n - j$ RVs are not smaller than $x$.
- The probability of the $i$th smallest RV being less than $x$, is the probability that, for some $j \ge i$, exactly the $j$ smallest RVs are less than $x$.
- For $j_1$ and $j_2$, $j_1 \ne j_2$, let $A$ be the event that exactly the $j_1$ smallest RVs are smaller than $x$, and let $B$ be the event that exactly the $j_2$ smallest RVs are smaller than $x$. Then $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events.

**Hint for finding the marginal PDF of the $i$th Rank**

You can find the derivative of $\frac{d \left( F_X(x)^j \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right)^{n - j}\right)}{d x}$ using the regular [derivate product and generalized power rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Generalized_power_rule).

**Hint for finding the joint CDFs/PDFs of the $i, j$ Ranks**

Generalize the previous two points. What needs to happen for the $i$th rank being less than $x_0$ and $j$th rank being less than $x_1$?

---

**Edit**

Following the comments below, here is how to find the expectation of $R_k^2$.

The probability that *exactly* the $j$ smallest $X$s will be at most $x$, is

$${n \choose j} F_X(x)^j \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right)^{n - j} .$$

The probability that the $i$th smallest $X$ will be at most $x$ is the sum of probabilities that exactly the $j$ smallest $X$s, for $j \ge i$, are smaller than $x$. This is

$$\sum_{j = i}^{n} \left[ {n \choose j} F_X(x)^j \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right)^{n - j }\right] .$$

which is exactly the CDF of $R_k$.

Differentiating, the PDF of $R_k$ is

$$\sum_{j = i}^{n} \left[ {n \choose j} j F_X(x)^{j - 1} f_X(x) \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right)^{n - j } - F_X(x)^j (n - j) \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right)^{n - j  - 1} f_X(x) \right] .$$ (1)

(This can be simplified a bit).

The integral of (1) multiplied by $x^2$ is the expectation of $R_k^2$.

Comment: would u mind to give me some steps to start? anyway thx for your help!!

Comment: @GillianCheung Looked around a bit, and it's pretty much spelled out [here](https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/the-distributions-of-the-order-statistics/). I'd suggest you first try using the above hints, though.

Comment: i know that once i got the pdf, i can do the integral to find the expectations and hence be able to find the covariance but i don't know the distribution.

Comment: @GillianCheung First, are you OK on the variance, then? You should have the PDF for that (either using the above hints, or the link I gave).

Comment: I cant find the variance, may be for demonstration can u show me how to find the expectation?I have derived the joint distribution follow the same idea and i have checked it.

Comment: @GillianCheung See if this helps you out.